# My mp3player freezes when I eject it

Tags: ubuntu, freeze, shutdown, safely-remove-hardware

When I eject(or safely remove) or unplug my mp3player from the USB, the screen freezes and an "ok to disconnect" message remains on its screen. Then I have to reset my mp3player. However when I shutdown my computer while the my3player is mounted it doesn't freeze and everything works correctly. I know this is a problem with my mp3player. The question is how can I eject my mp3player normally without forcing to shutdown the computer?

Comment: Without knowing the model we can't be of much help. However, with the symptoms you're describing I ask you if the mp3 player's manual states anything about removal procedures on the player's part. I would also ask you to try to safely remove in another machine. Lastly, why not just have the mp3 player turned off while it is connected to the PC?

Comment: The MP3 Player's brand and model is  is Iriver T7. I've tried safely remove on another machine with another OS and I got the same result so the MP3 Player is corrupt. When I connect it to the PC it truns on automaticaly(It's been planed this way). I also upgraded my MP3 Players's firemware and also formatted it nothing changed. My question is Why it unmounts correctly with no freeze when i shoutdown the computer?

Comment: Can I manually take the same steps as Shutdown, without shuting down in order to eject the MP3 Player correctly?